# Text expander program

Tags: software-recommendation

There are a plenty of [textexpander](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/productivity_tools/textexpander.html) programs for Mac OS X, but I wasn't able to find a good textexpander program for Ubuntu.

Could you please share some of them with me .

Comment: You could try [Snippits](http://rubygems.org/gems/snippits). I'm not posting this as an answer because I don't know how to use it. If it works for you, post an answer explaining how you used it and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[AutoKey](http://packages.ubuntu.com/autokey-qt) (Qt-based) and [AutoKey-GTK](http://packages.ubuntu.com/autokey-gtk), perhaps?

Comment: what's the difference between QT and GTK, i know GTK is for Gnome, right? but what means QT-based?

Comment: KDE is built on QT libraries -- so I'd go with the QT version if you were using Kubuntu or KDE, but as far s I know, both versions work on both GNOME and KDE; it's just that you might as well pick the one that loads the libraries that are already loaded by the DE to minimize overhead.