# Differences between Qt and GTK programs?

Tags: gtk, qt

Refering to [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18943/text-expander-program) question, there are two different versions of the Autokey program: Autokey (Qt-based) and Autokey-GTK. What are the differences between a Qt-based program and the GTK one and are there any differences from the point of view of the user?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

GTK and Qt are user interface toolkits and frameworks. GTK is the standard toolkit for GNOME/Ubuntu while Qt is used in KDE/Kubuntu. From the user's point of view I'd say it's just the looks that differ.

Comment: could you elaborate where the looks differ? afais plain-qt applications integrate seamlessly into e.g. ambiance desktops.

Comment: Actually,Qt applications blend in without a hitch most of the time wth your GNOME desktop.

Comment: There's going to be a lot more to it than that. The GTK based apps are going to rely on Gnome related stuff, like gsettings and dconf, which requires a service to run, whereas Qt based stuff may be KDE related and rely on kconfig. Stuff like that. I wish we could get proper answers for these kind of questions. "It's just the looks", huh?

Answer (score 3):

Another difference is that, if you are on Ubuntu, you may not already have all the QT stuff installed. On Kubuntu, you may not have all the GTK stuff installed. Hence it may make the download much bigger.

Comment: This should be a comment. It adds to an answer, but in itself is not an answer.

Comment: I disagree. It is an answer to the question. The question is "what are the differences?" and my Answer gives one of the differences. I note that one other Answer gives only one difference, while the top answer gives 2. No one Answer gives all the differences.

Comment: This is a better answer than all the others @JulianStirling. At least it starts to mention some of the significant differences you need to know about running these frameworks, instead of just "it looks different" or "GTK has a search feature".

Answer (score 2):

Aside from small differences in layout and appearance, the GTK version also has a quick search feature for shortcuts/abbreviations that QT doesn't have which allows you to use a hotkey like <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SPACE</kbd> to bring up a search box to quickly find abbreviations.  This helps quite a bit when you have hundreds of abbreviations to try to remember.