# Which KDE Plasma version should I choose

Tags: kde, plasma, plasma-5

I installed KDE plasma on my Ubuntu 20.04 using kde-standard but I now I found out more options like kde-full and kubuntu-desktop. I want to know which option should I use to have the complete KDE package while still preserving the default GNOME desktop .

Answer (score 2):

As from [this Ubuntu wiki article](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingKDE)

> These packages below are meta-packages -- they depend upon other, "real", packages, and with their installation they pull them in.

> ```
> kde-plasma-desktop -- Bare-minimum installation. Including basic utilities like a file manager, browser, and terminal emulator.
> ```

> ```
> kde-standard -- Everything in kde-plasma-desktop with a standard suit of system utilities (for example, calculator, email, media player, and advanced text editor)
> ```

> ```
> kde-full -- Everything in kde-standard with extra system utilities, games, and educational applications.
> ```

> kde-standard is recommended. You can install packages from kde-full afterwards if you want those extra features.

You can install the full `kde-full` package for example but never ever enable KDE as default desktop (*you need to do that manually from the login screen*) but be aware that as GNOME uses GTK and KDE Qt for graphics, you may get (*your mileage may vary depending on apps that you're using*) a bunch of graphical issues for the KDE apps in GNOME or as stated in this [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/249156/1133128) it may cause a higher than normal system resources usages

Comment: so I can install kubuntu-desktop without worrying about replacing GNOME or default apps, right?

Comment: This post is out of date. The recommended meta package is now `kde-standard`. I've installed this just now and verified that it has all I need and is not so monstrous like the `kde-full`.